# How to override "vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\web\js\price-utils.js" in our custom module Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, price

I have created the module, now I want to override the `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\web\js\price-utils.js` file in my custom module to change in one function.

I tried with below code:

- created `requrejs-config.js` file in the module as below:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils': 'Name_Module/js/price-utils-override'
        }
    }
};
```

then copy the file into my module `Name\Module\view\frontend\web\js\view\price-utils-override.js`.

after content deploy command. it is giving error as below "http://127.0.0.1/test/pub/static/version1545992807/frontend/theme/name/en_GB/Name_Module/js/price-utils.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)".

What is wrong here, please let me know if anyone has any idea about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below solution**

> requrejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils': 'Name_Module/js/view/price-utils-override'
        }
    }
};
```

**then run below CMD**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf generated/*
```

I think you missed **view** in requrejs-config.js file.

I hope it help..!!!

Comment: appreciated your answer but I am using the module not the theme.

Comment: @UtsavGupta try my new answer's code.

Comment: @UtsavGupta welcome :) . Please upvote my answer also so that will help another devlopers.